# Running a external program using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to launch a external program like notepad.exe using python. I want to have a script that just runs Notepad.exe.

Comment: Take a look at the `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple with Python's builtin `os` module.
This will start Microsoft Notepad:

```
import os

# can be called without the filepath, because notepad is added to your PATH
os.system('notepad.exe')
```

Or if you want to launch any other program just use:

```
import os

# r for raw-string, so don't have to escape backslashes
os.system(r'path\to\program\here\program.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done using Python OS. Please see the code below for an example.

```
import os
os.startfile('test.txt')
```

Startfile will execute the program associated with the file extension.

Comment: This could start any text  editor and not just Notepad, depending on the file extension associations.

Comment: Yes correct, not sure why you downvoted when I say that in my response.

Comment: could I run another program using `os.system`

Comment: Yes, any program can be run by os.system.

Comment: Maybe the downvote was for not answering the question. Question: "How can I start a specific external program". Answer: "Take a file and hope that the correct program is started"

Comment: The reason why I suggested using this, is because it generates the file in one step, rather than having to execute additional commands to generate your text file after opening notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend the `subprocess` module. Just build up a list of arguments like you would run in the terminal or command line if you are on windows then run it.

```
import subprocess

args = ['path\to\program\here\program.exe']
subprocess.call(args)
```

Check out [the docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for all of the other process management functionality.